# Cookie Saves as two different urls

Tags: php, html, variables, cookies, web

On my website, when users sign up or login, my site sometimes saves the cookie to "mywebsiteurl.com" and sometimes saves it to "www.mywebsiteurl.com".  In doing this, my code only works half the time.  Is there a way I can fix this issue from happening?

Comment: Would this be a problem regarding the URL the user types in or link he uses? I think you could solve this by always redirecting it to website.com instead of www.mywebsite.com

Comment: Please, remove `html` and `variables` tags as it has no connection to the question; remove  `website` tag as it marked as "DO NOT USE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set cookie in your PHP for your root domain and [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) will automatically make it available for all subdomains:

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', $someTimeToExpire, '/', 'mywebsiteurl.com');
```